# Not quite understanding a final step in an RSA licensing scheme

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am generating public and private keys. My private key stays with me and the public ships with the plugin binaries we sell. Customer plugin side we take a "fingerprint and hash it. Then along with some other implementation specifics we rsa encrypt it and send a lic. request over the web.

On our side server gets lic. request and decrypts using private key. Then pulls up customer, checks fingerprint for deltas and other such particulars like payment received.

Now the question I have is my response. Say everything checks out good. I need to respond to the request with a valid key. Generating the key on my side is easy enough and sending as a response is straight forward....but how does my plugin product know it is valid?

If I rsa encrypt it the plugin product...containing only the public key...can't decrypt it. If I embed some form of valid license checking code then it is easily disassembled and keys can be spoofed.

I know I can't make it crack proof. I am just looking to put deadbolts on doors and perhaps a security camera or two watching things...In essence making it less effort to pay for the product than buy all the equipment and spend time breaking in.

So to restate for clarity. The question isn't generating a license key response...although I am always willing to learn or hear other ideas.

The question is how, once the response is back to my customer plugin binary do I validate this is a key generated by me...and thus unlock the product for use.

Thank You very much for your patient assistance.

Answer (score 2):

To verify the response is from you you can *sign* it with the private key on the server and the client software can verify it with the public key. To make it slightly more secure you could use one key pair for encryption/decryption and one for signing/verifying.

If you want to decrypt on the client, then you can configure each client to use it's own key. If you cannot configure that you could derive a symmetric key from some device ID. Of course, you need to include the device ID with the encrypted request in that case. This is not a full-proof scheme either, but that's impossible without a trusted device anyway.

Comment: OK so I think that is perhaps my misunderstanding. I can verify from the public key but NOT decrypt.